# How To Read Data using Ip Address

Tags: c#, sockets

I am doing punch card reader programming..

Establish connection with BioAccess V2 Device...

socket successdully connected but data can't read...

so how to read data ?

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);  
var ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.000.111");  
IPAddress add = new IPAddress(ipaddress.GetAddressBytes());    
EndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(add, 5005);  
sock.Connect(ep);  
if(sock.connected)
{

}
```

now what i have to do in IF BLOCK to read data ?

Comment: Parsing an IP, then using that to create another! WTF?! Why does people code like that??

Comment: You'll have to implement the protocol of whatever thing you're talking to, what kind of application protokoll your "BioAccess V2 Device" use ?

Comment: Device uses TCP Protocol
port id : 5505

Comment: TCP is just the transport protocol, to do anything meaningful, there has to be a protocol above TCP - that's the protocol you have to implement, e.g. maybe you'll have to send something to the device first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the [`Socket.Receive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) overloads to read data.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
try 
{
    int i = server.Receive(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What is on the other end of the socket?