# Connect to remote host and read data using C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a server that streams data out on a TCP port once you connect to it. You can see this if you telnet to the TCP port and data starts flowing.

I am looking for an example that will let me connect to an IP address and port and receive the data in a stream in the application.

All examples I can find are with a client-server model with the client sending (which is not what I need) and the server binding to a port on itself and receiving.

I need this to be asynchronous and believe this can be done, but I could do with a good leg up!

Comment: Perhaps this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506217/how-to-read-data-using-ip-address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `TcpClient`, using `GetStream` for getting the `NetworkStream` and then use the stream for reading the data sent by the server. You can always use the stream asynchronously, using `BeginRead`.

If you are using a plain old `Socket`, you can use `BeginReceive` to receive asynchronously once connected.

Either way, as soon as you have a `NetworkStream` or a `Socket` object that is bound and connected, there is no difference between the server or the client. You can use the server example of reading in the client code, most often with no (or little) modification.

For an example:

```
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1000]; 

{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverHost, serverPort);
    NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, 1000, readHandler, tcpClient);
}

...

byte[] tempBuff = new byte[1000];
int tempBuffSize = 0;

// This is a rough example of reading and handling data
// that is delimited by \r\n. This code most probably is
// missing many edge case handling, so use it only as a starting
// point
void readHandler(IAsyncResult result)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState;
    int dataLen = tcpClient.GetStream().EndRead();

    int currStart = 0;
    int currEnd = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
    {
        if (readBuffer[i] == '\r' && i < (readBuffer.Length - 1) &&
            readBuffer[i + 1] == '\n')
        {
            // Set the end of the data
            currEnd = i - 1;

            // If we have left overs from previous runs:
            if (tempBuffSize != 0)
            {
                // Allocate enough space for the joined buffer
                byte[] joinedData = new byte[tempBuffSize + (currEnd - currStart + 1)];

                // Get the leftover from the previous read
                Array.Copy(tempBuff, 0, joinedData, 0, tempBuffSize);

                // And add the current read as well
                Array.Copy(readBuffer, currStart, joinedData, tempBuffSize, (currEnd - currStart + 1));

                // Now handle it
                HandleData(joinedData, 0, joinedData.Length);

                // Mark that we don't have any leftovers anymore
                tempBuffSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {               
                // Handle the data, from the start to the end, between delimiter
                HandleData(readBuffer, currStart, currEnd);
            }

            // Set the new start - after our delimiter
            currStart = i + 2;
        }
    }

    // See if we still have any leftovers
    if (currStart < dataLen)
    {
        Array.Copy(readBuffer, currStart, tempBuff, 0, dataLen - currStart);
        tempBuffSize = dataLen - currStart;
    }

    // Set the asynchronous read again
    stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, 1000, readHandler, tcpClient);
}
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you, good example.  Do you have any idea how I can construct lines from this.  All data is supposed to be terminated with chr(13) and chr(10)?

Comment: This is the big problem with TCP - it is a stream protocol. This means that there are no delimiters in the data sent by the server, unless the server does it by itself. The delimiter depends on the specific server implementation. For Telnet, this is indeed `\r\n\0`.

Comment: The server I am connecting to will produce a \r\n.  How do I collect this up into readable lines as at the moment it is just dumping out the buffer which is defined by number of bytes?

Comment: You'll need to collect the data you receive, and split according to the `\r\n` delimiter. Because you might receive a data item from the server that will be split across two asynchronous reads, you'll need to split by `\r\n` and keep any leftovers for the next `readHandler` invocation to add to the new data.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the new example!  Seems I can't use tcpClient.EndRead() though?

Comment: No problem. That's odd. What's the problem with using `EndRead`? Basically this is the function call that finalizes the asynchronous read, and must be called.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient' does not contain a definition for 'EndRead' and no extension method 'EndRead' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\lee armstrong\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DataFeeder\DataFeeder\Form1.cs 36 37 DataFeeder

Comment: Oops... You're right, the `EndRead` is a method of `NetworkStream`, not `TcpClient`. Need to use `GetStream()`. I've updated the code.